# ParseFloat array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsefloat

I'm trying to parse the values in my array then add them to a chart.  Problem is I'm getting some unexpected numbers on the out put.  I loop through and populate my array.  On the button click I loop through and parse the data and put it into another array to pass to a chart series.  This in theory works but the data points received are in accurate.  I've attached a picture of what the console out puts look like.  Once I parse it either i'm getting the first digit of the element or half of the number.

Thank you

[image]

Here is the code :

```
var testData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                
    testData[i] = populationData[i].Census;
    console.log(testData[i]);
}           

// the button action
$('#button').click(function () {

    var mySeries = [];
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        data[i] = parseFloat(testData[i]);
        mySeries[i] = data[i];                                       
    }

    console.log(mySeries);
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].setData(mySeries);
```

Comment: ParseFloat does not recognize `,` as thousand separator. Remove them first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas - JavaScript does not use thousand separators

```
parseFloat(testData[i].replace(/,/g,""));
```

or just

```
parseInt(testData[i].replace(/,/g,""),10);
```

if there are no decimals